# Is it possible to use Xcode to develop applications in languages other than ObjC, C, C++, assembly and Swift?

Tags: xcode, rust

As a concrete example, can I add a template for Rust that will allow me to develop, compile, and debug the application from inside Xcode?

My guess is that I would need to build a new Project Template that would configure all the needed XCode parameters like Build Settings, Build Phases, etc.. Setting up the compiler for the new language and supporting the new language characteristics (maybe a language that works on top of LLVM would be easier).

I noticed there is a file type selection box in the file inspector.
[image]

Could I add languages to this list?

Comment: How would Xcode suddenly and magically know how to compile and debug Rust?

Comment: @matt presumably in the same way that other IDEs can gain support for a new language: by being built to be extendable in the first place and then someone (or a group) produces a template, plug-in, extension, or whatever is appropriate that teaches the IDE how to do all the interesting IDE things. For example, [IntelliJ has some amount of Rust support](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust), Atom [has](https://atom.io/packages/build-cargo) some [packages](https://github.com/zargony/atom-language-rust), and there are [plans for other IDEs](https://www.rust-lang.org/ides.html) too.

Comment: @matt can you provide an explanation why it is impossible?

Comment: There's https://github.com/youknowone/rust-xcode-langspec, but it looks pretty old. Might be other projects like that around, too.

Comment: @Shepmaster , its name is LSP https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol; it transforms the Editor - Language compatibility from X*Y into X+Y; not every editor has to support every language. Instead, both editors and languages conform to a protocol, and what works on VSCode can work on vim or atom.